# How can I get SMS id on onReceive in android? Later Using that smsId I want to update the text of that sms, How is this possible?

Tags: java, android, sms

Here is how I am saving sms in java

```
private void saveSmsInInbox(Context context, SmsMessage sms) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SaveSmsService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("sender_no", sms.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
    serviceIntent.putExtra("message", sms.getDisplayMessageBody());
    serviceIntent.putExtra("date", sms.getTimestampMillis());
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AS of KitKat, only the default SMS app can write to the SMS databsse.  So unless you're the phone's SMS app chosen by the user, you cannot update the text of the SMS at a later time.

Comment: So what could be the best possible solution of it?

Comment: You just can't do it.  There is no solution.